# php during email input information doesnt get send

Tags: php, forms, email

i have been building a form with user input of course, now given the time to send the information via email. i get an email with all the information i have provided in the form, but only without the users actual input.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['Vorname'];
$firma =$_POST['firma'];
$strasse =$_POST['strasse'];
$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$tele = $_POST['tele'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea']; 


$email_to = "kchochlow@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "Information - rietho.de";


$email_from = $email;


$headers =  'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n\n\n" .



$email_subject = "Neue anfrage - Rietho.de";
$email_body = "Sie haben eine neue anfrage von $name arhalten \n\n".


"Name: \n  $name ". 
"Firma: \n  $firma ".
"Addresse: \n  $strasse ". 
"Email: \n  $email". 
"Telefon: \n  $tele ". 
"Fax: \n   $fax ". 

"Die anfrage:\n  $textarea \n\n ". 


'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail_sent = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);  

echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_all the information i have provided in the form, but only without the users actual input._" ? This is contradictory?

Comment: Umm can you `var_dump($_POST);` on top and see if it contains any values?

Comment: <p id="information"> name is:(information)</p><input type="text" id="user_actual_input"><p> user input </p>

hope this makes sense :D

Comment: user 007 ->  result for var_dump($_POST);
array(0) { }

Comment: Yes, so you see since the `$_POST` contains no values, you need to paste the code of the file which is calling this PHP file.

Comment: how is this being done? a particular code? or method

Comment: Can you paste the full code of the file which has the form in it?